# Redirect to https server in php

Tags: php, redirect, ssl

I am trying to redirect to a server that does Client authentication and establishes an https connection in php. I am using the following command:

```
header('Location:https://example.com');
```

But I cannot figure out how to send the client certificate in this redirect. without sending the certificate I cannot connect with the server. How can I attach the client certificate in the redirect?

Comment: installing a client cert is not something you can just spit out a `header()` call for...

Comment: first do you have a SSL cert installed on you web-server?

Answer (score 1):

> But I cannot figure out how to send the client certificate in this redirect.

You do not. Certificate are send by httpd much earlier (this phase of the protocol is called "handshake") than client and server start talking about dealing with your scripts (see: [How HTTPS actually works](http://robertheaton.com/2014/03/27/how-does-https-actually-work/)). You must set up correctly your httpd, install certificate and private key and perhaps certificate authority of certificate issuer (or your own CA if you are playing with self signed certs). There're lot of posts on the net about doing that, so google.

Comment: @Charanjit certificates are sent by the web-server, which typically... is apache (httpd), and yes Marcin is correct. Do you already have in SSL cert installed?

Comment: I have the server certificates installed on my server. I have my client certificate which the server asks for when doing the ssl handshake. I cannot find a way to send it in the php script,

Comment: The client and server certificates are self signed

Comment: You must send client your CA's public key and once he import it to his browser as trusted, browser will no longer complain

Comment: So my application is hosted on Nginx. I have login page where the user enters his credentials. Once the credentials are validated, I have a php script on the server that has to redirect the user to the other server that does client authentication. So I want to send the client.crt/client.pem programmatically in my php file.

Comment: No, you application is not hosted on nginx. Nginx is https server so it can be served by nginx at best, but definitely it is hosted elsewhere. 
As for the rest of your comment - you do not sent any client.crt/client.pem anywhere. Maybe your question is incorrectly asked - how exactly this authentication is expected to act?